# Read User Settings from a referenced project at runtime of a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I made a Windows Form GUI "config" app, which simply allows the user to change/save properties (like a decimal and a few strings). I have a Windows service which uses a timer to run a process every so often.

I would like the Windows service to pull settings from the config app. The furthest I've gotten so far is making the Config App settings "Public", and adding a reference to the config project in the service.

However, whenever I try to pull these settings, they are returning null?

Do I need to have a certain "privilege" for the service? I know there are different types of accounts for services, as well?

Or is the pattern I'm using for all of this incorrect/not efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Windows form application could write the properties in a file (an xml file for example) and then your service on every tick of the timer could open the file and read the values

Comment: This might be the easiest way to implement this for sure. .NET's/Windows settings/configuration complexities are getting to me.